# Force SSL on a single page which is used as iFrame

Tags: redirect, security, wp-redirect, ssl

I have one WordPress page that only contains a shortcode for a slider and is used by other websites as an iFrame.

I need to force SSL one this one single page, but whatever I try, it is not being redirected.

I have tried to achieve it through a following function:

```
function yst_ssl_template_redirect() {

        $page_id = 498;


        if ( is_page( $page_id )  && ! is_ssl() ) {

            if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
                wp_redirect(preg_replace('|^http://|', 'https://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 301 );
                exit();
            } else {
                wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
                exit();
            }
        } 
        if ( !is_page( $page_id )  && is_ssl() && !is_admin() ) {

            if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
                wp_redirect(preg_replace('|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 301 );
                exit();
            } else {
                wp_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
                exit();
            }
        }


    }
```

However, it always ends up in infinite redirect loop and does not get the work done.

I thought about a solution for forcing SSL through .htaccess, but I could not get it working for one single page.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated and if there is any additional information that I could provide - just tell me.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your original question, I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish what you are doing w/o the iframe, which is causing the problem.  If you post some detail on that aspect you will probably see some useful input on making this work.

Comment: I have updated the question with info that the page with the slider shortcode is used as an iFrame in other websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting redirected because of the automatic redirection to the canonical address of the page which is http://.... You will need to use the redirect_canonical filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/ to tell wordpress to not redirect for that page.